# What is the meaning of Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sanskrit, etymology

Ramayana is a sacred epic about the life of Lord Rama.

Can anyone explain the meaning/etymology of the word "Ramayana?"

Comment: Just an advice: Don't waste rep on bounty as you're already running low on rep. :-)

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya Possibly you will get perfect answer(s) without offering bounty as well.

Comment: We mean to say, this question is rather easy to answer. Many know the answer and even more can quickly research it. Perhaps later you will propose a question to which few know the answer. You can put a bounty on such questions to give people an incentive to research it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal meaning of *Ramayana* is **'The journey of Lord Rama'**.

Word *Ramayana* is comprised of words *Ram* + *Ayanam* by [Sanskrit Sandhi rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi). *Ayanam* is a *Sanskrit* word which means

> A path; A journey; Travel.

Iya / Aya > Ayana > Ayanam depicts a body motion, generally of coming towards, but not necessarily always.

In *Hindi*, *Aya* is derived from *Ayanam* refers specifically

> To come

In *Marathi* language, *ya* is referred to as 'to come' or 'to go' depending on context.

Comment: In a "subtle sense".. it is the journey(past, present and future) of sita-rama...prakriti-purusha....and centred in the Absolute truth.

Answer (score 7):

I think of it this way:

Ramayana = Ram + ayana

Here 'ayana' could be one of two thing:

1. coming - Story of Ram's Coming/Arrival
2. path/walking - the Path/walk/journey of Ram

Reference:
http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=ayana

Comment: Yes, Ayana - Approaching or belonging to.

Answer (score 0):

Monier-Williams [explains](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/monier/serveimg.pl?file=/scans/MWScan/MWScanjpg/mw0878-rAmavarNanastotra.jpg) the word as 'goings of Rāma and Sītā.'

> n. (Ramāyaṇa) Name of Vālmīki's celebrated poem, describing **the "goings"** **[*ayana*]** **of Rāma and Sītā**
>
> (it contains about 24000 verses in 7 books called Kāṇḍas, viz. 1. Bāla-kāṇḍa or Ādi-kāṇḍa; 2. Ayodhyā-kāṇḍa; 3. Araṇya-kāṇḍa; 4. Kiṣ-kindhyā-kāṇḍa; 5. Sundara-kāṇḍa-; 6. Yuddha-kāṇḍa; 7. Uttara-kāṇḍa; part of the 1st book and the 7th are thought to be comparatively modern additions; the latter gives the history of Rāma and Sītā after their re-union and installation as king and queen of Ayodhyā, afterwards dramatized by Bhava-bhūti in the Uttara-rāma-caritra; Rāma's character, as described in the Rāmāyaṇa, is that of a perfect man, who bears suffering and self-denial with superhuman patience; the author, Vālmīki, was probably a Brāhman connected with the royal family of Ayodhyā; and although there are three recensions of the poem, all of them go back to a lost original recension, the ground work of which, contained in books 2-6, in spite of many amplifications and interpolations, may be traced back to one man, and does not, like the Mahābhārata, represent the production of different epochs and minds)